# Create React App Stuck after a point "added 1416 packages in 2m"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, command-line, create-react-app

[My terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQf7d.png)

Help! I've been trying to create a react app on my machine. With the npx create-react-app my-app not working I have tried several commands, finally this command npx create-react-app@latest-version my-app is starting the installation but never goes further this point. Commands like npm start aren't working.

How do i solve this?

I've tried the command npx create-react-app@5.0.1 my-app

I expected react app to be created and it being able to run commands like npm start

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i did 2 things:

1. used `npm i react@latest then npx create-react-app app-name.`
2. changed internet service provider.

if that doesn't work, i suggest using a different pc/laptop and test it again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).